# Pip successfully installed module not found: ImportError: No module named xlwt

Tags: python, pip

My OS: win 10 ,

installed:

- python 2.7 ( command is `python`)
- python 3.9.5 ( command is `python3`)
- pip , pip3 ( both for python3, seems )

pip command:

```
c:\>pip3 config list -v
For variant 'global', will try loading 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\luelue\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\luelue\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'site', will try loading 'c:\users\luelue\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\pip.ini'

c:\>pip config list -v
For variant 'global', will try loading 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\luelue\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\luelue\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'site', will try loading 'c:\users\luelue\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\pip.ini'
```

I installed xlwt via `pip`, and I can see it's installed :

```
c:\>pip install xlwt
Requirement already satisfied: xlwt in c:\users\luelue\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\xlwt-1.3.0-py3.9.egg (1.3.0)
```

[image]

However, when I try to import it, got error: `No module named xlwt`

```
c:\>python
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xlwt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named xlwt
>>> exit()
```

Also, I used `pip3 install xlwt` successfully, but run `python3 ... import xlwt` failed. full log:

```
C:\files\dong_tai_pai_fang_ji_suan\python_code>pip3 install xlwt
Requirement already satisfied: xlwt in c:\users\luelue\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\xlwt-1.3.0-py3.9.egg (1.3.0)

C:\files\dong_tai_pai_fang_ji_suan\python_code>python3
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xlwt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt'
>>>
```

how to resolve this?

should I configure the windows PATH or something for python/pip ?

thanks

edit:

maybe I installed multiple python3:
[image]

Comment: In the first screenshot you are using python3.9, in the second screenshot python 2.7 - this is probably related - maybe run with the `python3` command?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use `virtualenv`, it's generally a good practice and it will save you a lot of problems down the line.

Comment: @M.Winkens python3 also failed, see my edit question

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko yeah, I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*maybe I installed multiple python3*

Do `python3 -m pip install xlwt`, this always install for `python3` (python launched when you do `python3` in terminal), then it should be possible to import installed module in `python3`. If you want to know more about that read [Installing Python Modules in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage).

Answer (score 2):

your python version is 2.7 in python console.
change to python 3.9 version.

Comment: running `python3 ... import  xlwt ` also failed.

Comment: please check.
import sys
print(sys.path)

Answer (score 0):

OK at last I find the root cause.

There are 2 versions of python in my PC:

1. version 3.9, this is installed by myself.
2. version 2.7, this is automatically installed by electron-vue

and I believe there are some conflicts between these two version's  configuration. ( e.g. execute path, pip path, etc )  which makes `pip install` work incorrectly.

solution is quite simple: uninstall all the python version and re-install 3.7, everything goes well!